# KQL parse string to json

Tags: kql

I'm having troubles to understand the following. Why can't I convert directly using parse_json() func but have to use tostring() first?

[image: Data types]

[image: Data type returned == string]

[image: Why can't I use the parse_json() function like this directly:]

[image: But have to apply the tostring func() first ?]

Not working:

```
|extend x = gettype(parse_json(Properties_d.requestbody))
```

Working:

```
|extend x = gettype(parse_json(tostring(Properties_d.requestbody)))
```

[Is it becuase:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoGRV.png)

Answer (score 1):

this is explicitly explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction):

[image]

Comment: So I have to convert a string with `tostring` to .... a string so that `parse_json` can parse it as dict ?